# Is the phrase "congenital birth defect" redundant?

Tags: phrases

con-gen-i-tal: ([m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congenital))

1. existing at or dating from birth [congenital deafness]
2. acquired during development in the uterus and not through heredity [congenital syphilis]

I ran across the  phrase *congenital birth defect* in a paper, and given the definition above it seems to be redundant.

Yet a simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22congenital%20birth%20defect%22&aq=f&oq=%22congenital%20birth%20defect%22&aqs=chrome.0.59j0l3j60.3113j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals a wide number of uses. Can anyone provide an authoritative explanation about this?

Comment: I suppose it's possible for a _birth defect_ to be hereditary. According to Definition #2, then, a "congenital birth defect" might be referring specifically to one that is not hereditary.

Comment: @J.R.: Yeah...but, since *congenital* usually has a broader meaning (correct me if I'm wrong), that sounds like a bad idea: just use some other term to specify a defect acquired as an embryo, such as *in utero* or *embryogenic*.

Comment: Congenital birth defects (as labelled) also refer to cases where certain mechanisms of causation are known. Because teratogenic toxicology has so many unknowns there are a number of birth defects not-labelled as being congenital because the causal link has not yet been made.

Comment: @batpigandme +1 You could add some references and post that as an  answer I suppose.

Comment: "What do people think?" is off-topic on ELU. Ask for canonical answers.

Comment: @batpigandme: That's an interesting hypothesis, that "congenital" is a label applied to birth defects with known causes. I would have to see a reference, though. For one thing, the website http://toxipedia.org/display/toxipedia/Teratogens seems to use "congenital malformations" and "birth defects" interchangeably. Maybe the phrase is just simply redundant, but has a nice ring to it so people use it anyway?

Comment: @Kris: You could have edited this last four words of this post, instead of leaving a comment like that.

Comment: @Cerberus: I'm not going to correct you; we're outside of my knowledge domain here. I was merely speculating – offering a conjecture that might point someone in the right direction.

Comment: @Kris if I knew where my textbooks from Molecular Mechanisms of Oncogenisis and Teratogenic Toxicology were I would do so happily... I'll hold my tongue in the future when I don't have references on hand.

Comment: @batpigandme If it points folks in the right direction, it's still helpful.

Comment: @J.R. No, one should **not** -- nor advise so others to -- editing is **not** for that.

Comment: @batpigandme Easy. Your knee-jerk reaction is misplaced. Notice that I had up voted your comment. You can always look online -- even your "textbooks from Molecular Mechanisms of Oncogenisis and Teratogenic Toxicology" could be right there in full or part text, who knows. :) See also comment by Bradd Szonye above.

Comment: @Kris: You have your opinion, I have mine. I thought your comment could be perceived as rude, and feel like you could have accomplished the same objective with an edit.

Comment: @Kris my bad! A rough day on the boards (elsewhere) had me on the defensive... I couldn't find my own textbook online, but found a different one and turns out I was wrong to begin with! (Though I swear if I ever find that book that it led me astray...)

Comment: @batpigandme Great effort. I've up voted your answer.

Comment: @ktm5124 yeah I was wrong there! I wonder if it's akin to saying "pediatric childhood illness"  (redundant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I believe the answer is yes. Congenital anomalies (or congenital defects) are, inherently present at birth. The World Health Organization's first 'key fact' about [congenital anomalies](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs370/en/) states:

> Congenital anomalies (also referred as birth defects) affect
>   approximately 1 in 33 infants and result in approximately 3.2 million
>   birth defect-related disabilities every year.

Congenital can refer to different mechanisms of causation [Brent and Fawcett 2007][reference]:

> the etiology of congenital malformations can be  divided into three
>   categories: unknown, genetic, and environ-  mental

[reference]: Brent, RL and Fawcett, LB: Developmental toxicology, drugs, and 
fetal teratogenesis. In Reece EA, Hobbins JC (eds.) Clinical 
Obstetrics: The Fetus and Mother, 3rd edition, Blackwell Publishing 
Inc., Malden, MA, Chapter 15, pp. 217-235, 2007.

Comment: I am confused about your assertion that there are birth defects which are not congenital. What am I missing?

Comment: @horatio That part of it is way outside my wheelhouse (not sure I totally get that part either), so I removed it . I think if might have to do with obstetric injury.

Comment: I did some very very cursory digging, and there is a little of both. Seems like a grey area, but I am no longer confused about what you meant. It is certainly outside of my expertise as well.

Comment: @batpigandme Hey again, thank you for your research! The WHO is a great reference. It's always nice to pick out the redundant phrases in common usage.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what *[Merriam-Webster's Medical Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/congenital)* says about *congenital*:

> 1 : existing at or dating from birth (congenital deafness)
>   2 : acquired during development in the uterus and not through heredity (congenital syphilis)  compare ACQUIRED 2, FAMILIAL, HEREDITARY

and here's what it says about *[congenital adrenal hyperplasia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/congenital%20adrenal%20hyperplasia)*

> any of several **hereditary** disorders that are marked by inadequate synthesis of cortisol due to an enzyme deficiency determined by a defect in an autosomal recessive gene, that are typically characterized by excessive production of androgens, virilization of female external genitalia, and hypertension, and that include a severe form in which inadequate synthesis of aldosterone results in potentially fatal hyponatremia and hyperkalemia shortly after birth—(abbreviation: CAH)

The usage doesn't always mean hereditary or not hereditary: it can mean either. Some congenital conditions are genetically transmitted (hereditary) and some are caused by developmental problems with exogenous (external, not genetic) causes.

Comment: Good idea to check the medical dictionary. Looks like something that's "congenital" doesn't imply heredity one way or the other.